# Typescript incorrect type union in instantiating new class object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a `Logger` class in typescript that takes an optional `options` parameter in its constructor with a `class` `generic` `C` that represent custom levels. This type is used within the class for methods such as `log(level: Level<C>)`. Now, I want an `updateConfig` method that returns a new `Logger` instance where its `C` parameter is a union of the 'father's' custom levels + those defined in the new options object.

I have:

```
type DefaultLevel = 'info' | 'error'; // Default log levels

type Level<C extends string> = DefaultLevel | C
type LevelWithSilence<C extends string> = Level<C> | 'silence'

interface LoggerOptions<C extends string> {
  customLevels?: Record<C, number>
  level: LevelWithSilence<NoInfer<C>>
}

interface UpdatedLoggerOptions<C extends string, L extends string> {
  customLevels?: Record<L, number>
  level: LevelWithSilence<NoInfer<C | L >>
}

class Logger<C extends string = ''> {

  options?: LoggerOptions<C>

  constructor(options?: LoggerOptions<C>) {
    this.options = options
  }

  log(level: Level<C>, message: string) {
    // Log message
  }

  updateConfig<L extends string = never>(options?: UpdatedLoggerOptions<C, L>) {
    
    if(!this.options) return new Logger (options as LoggerOptions<C>)

    if(!options) return this

    return new Logger<C | L>({
      customLevels: {
        ...this.options.customLevels as Record<C, number>,
        ...options.customLevels as Record<L, number>
      },
      level: options.level
    } as LoggerOptions<C | L>)
  }
}

// Usage
const logger = new Logger({
  customLevels: {
    debug: 1,
    trace: 2,
  },
  level: 'error'
});

logger.log('debug', '')

const newLogger = logger.updateConfig({
  customLevels: {
    test: 3,
  },
  level: 'test'
})

newLogger.log('debug', '') // Works
newLogger.log('test', '') // Should work
```

Everything appears to be typesafe apart from the `log` method. `newLogger.log('debug', '')` works, indicating that it clearly extracted the father's custom levels. On the other hand, `newLogger.log('test', '')` gives me error: `Argument of type '"test"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Level<"debug" | "trace">'.` indicating that it failed 'extrapolating' the custom levels from the options object.

Furthermore, upon hovering over the `logger` object, i get as a type: `const logger: Logger<"debug" | "trace">`, while hovering over `newLogger` I get `const newLogger: Logger<"debug" | "trace"> | Logger<"debug" | "trace" | "test">`.

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: Thanks. Is there some purpose to using `''` as the default? Seems like that doesn't ever happen. Or why you don't do anything in your constructor? If you're just asking about typings, that's one thing, but then I'd say you've mostly got them and you just need to clean it up to [this](https://tsplay.dev/WyVGdw). If you're asking about *implementation* then it's up to you to show others how you actually initialize your class properties.  Right now there's no property of type `LoggerOptions<C>` anywhere, so I'm not sure what you expect to see.

Comment: See prev comment. Also, please note, the point of my comment about returning a new instance wasn't intended to have you alter the question to incorporate it; I would expect that stuff would be in the answer and not the question. (Future readers will benefit from "Q: how do I do this; A: you do it this way" more than "Q: how do I do this EDIT I was told to do it this way but now I have a followup question; A: uh, okay, here's the answer to the followup")

Comment: Ok, sorry I will keep this in mind for future questions. I updated the question with failing implementation.

Comment: So it's the implementation? I suppose I'd do it [this way](https://tsplay.dev/W4aMew) keeping in mind that you'll need type assertions or the like to convince the compiler to accept it. Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining, but please, [edit] for *this question* so that it asks a single well-defined question that doesn't appear as a series of edits that converges on a solution. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Yes it indeed solved the issue. I will fix this question and close the other one. Sorry but I didn't see your comment.

Comment: @jcalz Also, in your answer i'd love for you to explain why my approach didn't work. I actually made the question because I want to learn the type system deeply, hence why I didn't have an implementation and a Minimum Reproducible Example. Also, if you have any suggestions on resources /  documentation other then the official one I can use to learn.

Comment: I'll write an answer when I get a chance.

Comment: But I have to say I'm disappointed to see so much of my suggested code folded into your question. It makes me feel like you're just using me as personal tech support and not contributing back to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry. This wasn't my intention. I felt like the question  was getting a bit messy and its evolution diverted from the original inquiry. Hence I thought it would've been more valuable to the platform in this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the question as currently stated, the only issue is that you need the return type of `updateConfig` to be `Logger<C | L>` so that the returned value will accept things from both `C` and `L`:

```
updateConfig<L extends string = never>(
  options?: UpdatedLoggerOptions<C, L>
): Logger<C | L> { ⋯ }
```

The implementation will need [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) or the like, so that you can convince the compiler that you are actually returning a `Logger<C | L>`, since it won't be able to understand the case analysis for generics that says, for example, "if `options` is missing then `this` is already a `Logger<C | L>` because we expect `L` to be `never`." So, when necessary, double check that your assumption about the type is correct (or unlikely to be violated in practice) and then assert:

```
updateConfig<L extends string = never>(options?: UpdatedLoggerOptions<C, L>): Logger<C | L> {

  if (!this.options) return new Logger(options as LoggerOptions<C | L>)
  // ----------------------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  if (!options) return this as Logger<C | L>
  // ---------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  return new Logger({
    customLevels: {
      ...this.options.customLevels as Record<C, number>,
      // ------------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      ...options.customLevels as Record<L, number>
      // -------------------> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    },
    level: options.level
  })
}
```

Those assertions make things compile without error. Let's make sure you can use it as desired:

```
const logger = new Logger({
  customLevels: {
    debug: 1,
    trace: 2,
  },
  level: 'error'
});

logger.log('debug', '')

const newLogger = logger.updateConfig({
  customLevels: {
    test: 3,
  },
  level: 'test'
})

newLogger.log('debug', '') // Works
newLogger.log('test', '') // Works
```

Looks good.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ACmBsZzmGdXM2wLIsS3klFyPA6QVKTPRTEmABmMy9LYqzUuAHJeLkWtN2C1yAw89TNJ8khiFtQTPDYABrWRitK-13Ly6q-OTKBNyaqQgA)

Answer (score 1):

Well, long story short, constructor is privileged in this unjust world of OOP, that when it's called, there is no real class instantiated. So when you call:

```js
    class Foo<T extends string = '', V extends string = ''> {
       constructor(opts?: T) {}
    }
    
    // there is no instance of `Foo` existing, types are inferred from non-existent
    
    const foo = new Foo('abc');
    
    // to existing - at this point constructor was able to infer the desired
    // type of T, and because there was nothing to work the type V from, this 
    // type couldn't have been inferred from anything - therefore was set to 
    // default
```

If it was implemented otherwise, that'd be a serious break of type-safety, see what would happen if you did:

```js
    type DefaultLevel = 'info' | 'error';
    
    type Level<C extends string> = DefaultLevel | C
    type LevelWithSilence<C extends string> = Level<C> | 'silence'
    
    interface LoggerOptions<C extends string> {
      customLevels?: Record<C, number>
      level: LevelWithSilence<NoInfer<C>>
    } 
    
    class Logger<C extends string = '', V extends string = ''> {
    
      constructor(options?: LoggerOptions<C>) { // this is equivalent to setting also V without specified value
        // Initialization based on options
      }
    
      log(level: Level<C>, message: string) {
        // Log message
      }
    
      setPrimaryConfig(config: LoggerOptions<C>) {}
    
      setSecondaryConfig(config: LoggerOptions<V>) {}

}
```

why would `setPrimaryConfig` be forbidden to mutate `C`, whereas `V` - not? These are **identical** functions. Why should one be allowed to mutate type of the class, whereas another one - not? I mean, the concept of type-safety has been coined to ensure, well, type-safety - so once instantiated object doesn't get its type mutated. And attempt to mutate generic type V on Foo<T..., V...> after Foo is constructed is, well, making a type of the same object fluctuating.

Now, assume this:

```js
    class Foo<T extends string = '', V extends string = ''> {
        constructor(opts?: T) {}
        private secondaryOpts?: V;
        setSecondary(opts: V) {
           this.secondaryOpts = opts;
        }
    
        get secondaryOptsOrFalse (): V extends '' ? false : V {
            return this.secondaryOpts ?? false;
        }
    
    }
    
    const foo = new Foo('abc');
    const firstForSecondaryOpts = foo.secondaryOpts // type false;
    foo.setSecondary('def');
    // if types were mutable, we'd have
    const secondForSecondaryOpts = foo.secondaryOpts // type is 'def';
```

As a result, we won't be able even to run:

```js
    firstForSecondaryOpts === secondForSecondaryOpts
```

because there would be no overlap in types between `first...` (false) and `second...` (string)

---

Besides, constructor's role is to *construct*, build. Constructor works on a plan, a blueprint, a guide to build some object. If other methods were able to override constructor's blueprint, then any type would gain the potential to mutate over time. Which makes the whole idea of types in TS quite pointless :)

**And there are a lot of other examples here.** Like, if you can change the generic type of a class after it's constructed, any methods operating on that type before and after setting secondary config would have to *switch* their operational logic to reflect changes in types.

---

Besides!
You defined `LevelWithSilence<C extends string> = Level<C> | 'silence'`, so even if anything else might work/not work, we have the first immutability here.

---

So, **first things last**. Reconsider what you intend to achieve, and if you really need that, and what for. Sometimes, quite often even, too much flexibility on types kills the whole idea of immutability.